# Nginx: Disallow index.html in URL

Tags: nginx, static-files

We're generating a site consisting of only static files (using [Assemble](http://assemble.io/)).

Having the .html extension on URLs looks so nineties, so we generate every static HTML file in its own directory and call it index.html. For example, the url http://www.example.com/foo/bar/ is in the file `/var/www/foo/bar/index.html`.

This works well, but there is one small thing nagging me: Now there are two possible URLs to the same resource:

1. http://www.example.com/foo/bar/ (slash URL)
2. http://www.example.com/foo/bar/index.html (index.html URL)

By accident someone may link to the index.html form of the URL, which is bad for SEO and looks ugly (remember the nineties?).

Is it possible in Nginx to give a 404 error on the index.html URL, but serve the slash URL?

I tried this:

```
location ~ /index\.html$ {
    return 404;
}
```

But it seems that Nginx does some internal rewrite of the slash URL to the index.html URL, and then matches this location so we get a 404 even on the slash URL.

Note that to catch mistakes, we want index.html URLs to be an *error*, not just redirect to the slash URL.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that `index.html` is *actually* bad for SEO? Search engines have been quite good at figuring out that sort of non-malicious duplicate content situation and picking the canonical URL for years now (as they have with www vs. non-www).

Comment: Nope, that's just something I heard. It's bad for caching in any case.

Answer (score 0):

There is an internal redirect for index.html as it is the default `index`; the `/` request redirects to `/index.html` which is set to return 404.

You can check the [ngx_http_index_module documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html) to get a better understanding. Your case is documented.

An approach for your issue would be to rename all `index.html` to `foo.bar` and add that filename as default `index`

```
location / {
    index foo.bar;
}
```

Comment: It's a bit of a hack, but that should work. Nobody links to foo.bar by accident. :-)